Read password protected .doc file with Java
I have been reading password protected .docx files with org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem as follows
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(path)
POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis)
EncryptionInfo info = new EncryptionInfo(fs);
Decryptor decryptor = Decryptor.getInstance(info);

if (!decryptor.verifyPassword(password)) {
    throw new EncryptedDocumentException("Incorrect password");
    }
InputStream dataStream = decryptor.getDataStream(fs);

This works just fine. Now I need the equivalent for a .doc file. The above code fails since there is no such thing as EncryptionInfo in a .doc file.
Ive explored the following options:

Aspose.Words: This seems to be the best option, its licensed
OpenOffice / UnoAPI: it works locally, but I can not install OpenOffice in prod
JODConverter: does not support password protected .doc

Am I missing something here? reading a .doc file with Java sounds like a very simple thing to do, any ideas ? Thanks!

Are you talking about a write protected document or a document where you need the password to display/read anything? If it is the latter you should check if supporting this special case of a proprietary document format is really required for your software.

Hi Robert, the second one. A .doc where you need the password to display/read.

Reading password-protected .doc files (binary Microsoft Word documents) with Java can be challenging because they use a different encryption mechanism compared to .docx. Unlike .docx, which is based on OpenXML and supported by libraries like Apache POI, .doc files are in a proprietary binary format and require specialized tools for decryption.

use Use Aspose.Words but you need Licensing
